# Get part of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

How can I get coordinates from string:

```
<path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M275.843,110.301c-47.082,13.406-77.458,58.874-69.425,103.478
        c4.241,23.548,16.136,42.268,38.639,52.408c4.728,2.13,10.717,1.457,16.125,2.08c25.394,2.925,46.609,15.095,66.295,30.378
        c3.857,2.995,6.64,2.91,10.014-0.096c24.818-22.111,39.262-49.192,39.892-84.204c-0.189-2.728-0.244-6.743-0.775-10.694
        c-5.566-41.427-27.104-72.584-61.608-95.299c-1.563-1.029-3.687-1.618-5.573-1.682
        C298.075,106.287,286.912,107.148,275.843,110.301z"></path>
```

I need all coordinates after `d="` to `"`, so I need only numbers:

```
M275.843,110.301c-47.082,13.406-77.458,58.874-69.425,103.478
            c4.241,23.548,16.136,42.268,38.639,52.408c4.728,2.13,10.717,1.457,16.125,2.08c25.394,2.925,46.609,15.095,66.295,30.378
            c3.857,2.995,6.64,2.91,10.014-0.096c24.818-22.111,39.262-49.192,39.892-84.204c-0.189-2.728-0.244-6.743-0.775-10.694
            c-5.566-41.427-27.104-72.584-61.608-95.299c-1.563-1.029-3.687-1.618-5.573-1.682
            C298.075,106.287,286.912,107.148,275.843,110.301z
```

or how can i get this value of d. Becouse target return me this all informations but when i write

```
target.d
```

there nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla javascript:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').getAttribute('d');
```

With jquery use .attr():

```
$('#elementId').attr('d');
```

Comment: This is a string, not an HTML element.

Comment: this is target from click event: event.target return me "path"

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with a Regexp :

```
var myString = '<path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M275.843,110.301c-47.082,13.406-77.458,58.874-69.425,103.478c4.241,23.548,16.136,42.268,38.639,52.408c4.728,2.13,10.717,1.457,16.125,2.08c25.394,2.925,46.609,15.095,66.295,30.378c3.857,2.995,6.64,2.91,10.014-0.096c24.818-22.111,39.262-49.192,39.892-84.204c-0.189-2.728-0.244-6.743-0.775-10.694c-5.566-41.427-27.104-72.584-61.608-95.299c-1.563-1.029-3.687-1.618-5.573-1.682C298.075,106.287,286.912,107.148,275.843,110.301z"></path>';

var myRegexp = /d=\"(.*|\s)\">/g;

var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
```

What you want is then :

```
match[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method:

```
event.target.getAttribute('d')
```